# Reading S3 files from a manifest and processing them in parallel using Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have about 50k to read from S3 using a manifest file. I have to read contents of every single (JSON) file into a dataframe and process the files (normalize them as database tables). Right now I have a working code that take about 15hours to process the 50k files. I have to run this as a daily job. Is there any way to parallel process larger amount to files or any better way to speed up process?

Updating the question with the code

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
import os
import gzip
import boto3
from datetime import datetime,timezone,timedelta


session = boto3.session.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')
client = session.client('s3')

#read the S3 inventory report, get the keys of files that are modified on sysdate-1   
dt=(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=-1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
dtz=dt+'T00-00Z'
print('reading inventory report for', dtz)
inventory_bucket = 'xxx'
manifest_key='s3-bucket'+dtz+'/manifest.json'
manifest = json.load(s3.Object(inventory_bucket, manifest_key).get()['Body'])
df=pd.DataFrame()
for obj in manifest['files']:
        gzip_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=inventory_bucket, key=obj['key'])
        print('csv obj:', gzip_obj)
        buffer = gzip.open(gzip_obj.get()["Body"], mode='rt')
        reader = pd.read_csv(buffer)
        reader.columns=['id','key','modified_date']
        print('converting csv obj to dataframe')
        df=df.append(reader[(reader.modified_date>dt)])
source_keys=list(df['key'])
s3_bucket_source='yyy'

#download the files to a tmp folder
local='/tmp/'
print("downloading from S3")
for k in source_keys:
  k_path=k.replace('/', '-')
  dest_pathname = os.path.join(local, k_path)
  if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
      os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
      client.download_file(s3_bucket_source, k, dest_pathname)

#read the latest jsons from tmp folder
path_to_json =  os.path.expanduser('/tmp/') 
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]

#loop through the jsons and normalize each file contents into df_table1, df_table2, df_table3
for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        print('processing file:', js)
        d=json.loads(json_file.read())
        v=d['key1'][0]['key2']
        if isinstance(v, list):
                for i, v2 in enumerate(v): 
                    df_table1, df_table2, df_table3 = normalizeJSON(d,i,v2['id']) 
                    #normalize is the custom function to split the nested json into relational tables 
        else:
            print('invalid json')
```

I use the S3 inventory report to get the list of most recent modified files from the manifest, download the files to a tmp location and read them one by one to do what I need to do

Comment: You run that on AWS infrastructure, or you want to parallelize on your workstation?

Comment: @Marcin I run the code on AWS Infrastructure , using AWS Glue at the moment

Comment: @Smile updated the question with the code snippet

Comment: The slowest part is downloading all the files in Python sequentially. A simple improvement would be do download using gnu parallels and awscli. Another option is using gevent in in order to download many files in parallel -- see this code for a similar example https://gist.github.com/pcdinh/3495566

Comment: If you are using Glue to process the data, why aren’t you using Spark? spark with EMRFS would be great option. You don’t have to download the data manually

Comment: What's the end result? Are you loading into another database?

Comment: Would it be an option to convert your json files into feather format and than run your code? Computation with feather files is much faster. Downside: you have to convert the files first and conversion + calculation is slower. So only an option when the conversion could be done separately

Answer (score 1):

You use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) to download JSON files in parallel. 
You code contains 3 *for* blocks. You can do each one of them in parallel. An example of how to do this for the first *for* follows:

The first *for*:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for obj in manifest['files']:
        gzip_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=inventory_bucket, key=obj['key'])
        print('csv obj:', gzip_obj)
        buffer = gzip.open(gzip_obj.get()["Body"], mode='rt')
        reader = pd.read_csv(buffer)
        reader.columns=['id','key','modified_date']
        print('converting csv obj to dataframe')
        df=df.append(reader[(reader.modified_date>dt)])
```

becomes:

```
def get_reader(obj):
    gzip_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=inventory_bucket, key=obj['key'])
    print('csv obj:', gzip_obj)
    buffer = gzip.open(gzip_obj.get()["Body"], mode='rt')
    reader = pd.read_csv(buffer)
    reader.columns=['id','key','modified_date']
    print('converting csv obj to dataframe')
    return reader[(reader.modified_date>dt)]

num_of_workers = 4
df = pd.DataFrame()
with multiprocessing.Pool(num_of_workers) as p:
    results = p.map(get_reader, manifest['files'])

for result in results:
    df = df.append(result)
```

You can do the same for the other *for* blocks

Comment: when i tried to parallelize my last **for** i get the below error `TypeError: map() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: thanks for your reply @pakallis. I fixed the error and Im able to run the code. the third for block in the code returns 8 data frames. but the output of map function is a list. So results in this case is a tuple of 8 dataframes. Is there any way to have map function output the 8 dataframes ?